# Iterate <option> value with button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a `<select>` element that is populated from a json file:

```
<select ng-model="selected_ad" ng-options="ad.title for ad in ads">
  <option value="">Select an Ad</option>
</select>
```

Would it be possible to change the `<option>` value attribute using a button?

For example...

The output for the `select` element is:

```
<select ng-model="selected_ad" ng-options="ad.title for ad in ads" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<option value="" class="">Select an Ad</option>
<option value="0">Business Development 1</option>
<option value="1">Business Development 2</option>
<option value="2">Business Development 3</option>
<option value="3">Business Development 4</option>
...
```

Can I create a button, perhaps with `ng-click` that loops through each element and dynamically changes the selected option? I've played with it for a bit and can't find anything relevant in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should be using either the Object syntax in ng-options:

```
select as label for (key , value) in object
```

Or the Array syntax:

```
select as label for value in array
```

This will set both the display label in the option (what you see) and the value option for your ng-model.

Currently when you're using `label for value in array` you are only setting the label of the option. Lets say your data model $scope.ads can look like this:

```
$scope.ads = [
    { title = 'Business Development 1',
      value = 'bizdev1'
    },
    { title = 'Business Development 2',
      value = 'bizdev2'
    }....
    ];
```

Then when you will use `ng-options = 'ad.value as ad.title for ad in ads'`, your displayed option will stay the same, but now selected one of the options will cause your `ng-model` to contain the value of the object and not just a number.

If you need to dynamically change the value - no need to jQuery loop through anything, Angular has 2 way data-binding so that if you change the value in the `$scope.ads` your `select` element's value will change with it.

For further info on this, checkout [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)

**edit** - if you want to change the actual values themselves after a ng-click you can do so by looping through the data and increment it by 1 (in that case it would make more sense to leave the values as integers.

If you want to just have a button that selects a certain option (lets say using a ng-model from an input box) you can do so by changing the *select* ng-model, i.e: `selected_ad`. Change it to the value of what you want selected.

**edit 2** - Just change your dataset like so:

```
$scope.selected_ad = 1;

$scope.ads = [
{ title = 'Business Development 1',
  value = 1
},
{ title = 'Business Development 2',
  value = 2
}
];
```

and add a controller logic change:

```
$scope.changeSelection = function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   ++$sccope.selected_ad;
}
```

And in your select dom element:

```
<select ng-model="selected_ad" ng-options ='ad.value as ad.title for ad in ads' ng-click="changeSelection($event)">
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I see what you're getting at, but I still can't quite get my puny brain to connect the two concepts.

I want the `ng-model` to increment by 1 through the list on each button click.

The best way to do that would be to leave the values as numbers, no?

Comment: In response to the 2nd paragraph of the edit:

`ng-click="selected_ad.value += 1"`

Does not work in this manner. Any idea why that might be?

**edit** I'm guessing there's a new scope created with `ng-options`, but I can't figure out how to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you get all the data from `ads` array (or object) and Angular can track data changes, it's possible to change original set of data in order to update options. For example, this function will increment values by 10:

```
 $scope.switchAds = function () {
    $scope.ads.forEach(function (ad) {
      ad.value += 10;
    });
  };
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ElUhas/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: This is close, but it isn't quite what I was aiming for.

I don't want to change the value, I want to change the selection.

In other words:

click->Business 1, click->Business 2, click->Business 3, and so on.